# Minimum of the ratio of normal cdf and square of the pdf

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimization

I am having a little hard time figuring out if there is a minimum of the following ratio:
$$ \frac{\Phi(x)(1 - \Phi(x))}{\phi^2(x)},$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf and $\phi$ is the standard normal pdf.

Can we somehow demonstrate that the function is convex and proceed from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using
$$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)$$
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma }e^{-\frac{(x-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}$$ Let $t=\frac{x-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }$ which make
$$\frac{\Phi(x)(1 - \Phi(x))}{\phi^2(x)}=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sigma ^2 e^{2 t^2} \left(1-\text{erf}(t)^2\right)$$ Now, consider
$$f(t)=e^{2 t^2} \left(1-\text{erf}(t)^2\right)$$

The first derivative
$$f'(t)=4 e^{t^2} \left(e^{t^2} t
   \left(1-\text{erf}(t)^2\right)-\frac{\text{erf}(t)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)$$ cancels at $t=0$ and the second derivative
$$f''(t)=-\frac{24 \sqrt{\pi } e^{t^2} t \text{erf}(t)+4 \pi  e^{2 t^2} \left(4 t^2+1\right)
   \left(\text{erf}(t)^2-1\right)+8}{\pi }$$
$$f''(0)=4-\frac{8}{\pi } \quad >0$$ So the minumum value is
$$\frac{\pi  \sigma ^2}{2}$$

In fact, expanded as a series around $x=\mu$, the expression is
$$\frac{\pi  \sigma ^2}{2}+\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-1\right) (x-\mu )^2+\frac{(3 \pi -8)
   (x-\mu )^4}{12 \sigma ^2}+\frac{(15 \pi -44) (x-\mu )^6}{180 \sigma
   ^4}+O\left((x-\mu )^8\right)$$ where all coefficients are positive.